# Multiple Owl V2 sliders using single javascript declaration and .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Been trying various things, and searched around expecting others to have done the same, but getting nowhere fast .. the best result i've got is the first instance of the carousel working, but all the rest do not. Why is the .each() function not working?

Note: the main aim is to have multiple carousels with one block of .js control  .. the script pulls the individual carousel instance variables such as number of items to show, delay, if lazy-load or not, theme classes, etc from each instance based on the data-variable="xyz" values ... and it works fine with individually identified (used unique classes or ID's) carousels on the page, but not this (more efficient) multi method.

As you see i've tried to find the carousels based on the common class ".galleryowlmulti", then find their parent container ID to uniquely identify it (as i thought this is the issue?) and then apply the variables to each carousel instance. Hope that makes sense?

Example HTML Snippet of one slider repeated in the same page but with unique ID's (please note that ".owl-carousel" is not needed where I use ".owlcarousel") :

```
<span id="unique-id1" class="slider">               
      <span class="titleh3">Title</span>            
      <div class="galleryowlmulti" data-owlitemshow="8" data-owlmargin="10" data-owltimeout="4000" data-owllazy="true" data-owldots="false" data-owlautoplay="false" data-owlslideby="page" data-owlthemes="owltheme-smallnav">
          <div class="owlcarousel">                 
            <div class="item">1st slide</div>
            <div class="item">2nd slide</div>   
          </div>        
      </div>                
</span>
<span id="unique-id2" class="slider">               
      <span class="titleh3">Title</span>            
      <div class="galleryowlmulti" data-owlitemshow="8" data-owlmargin="10" data-owltimeout="4000" data-owllazy="true" data-owldots="false" data-owlautoplay="false" data-owlslideby="page" data-owlthemes="owltheme-smallnav">
          <div class="owlcarousel">                 
            <div class="item">1st slide</div>
            <div class="item">2nd slide</div>   
          </div>        
      </div>                
</span>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
 $('.galleryowlmulti').each(function() {

    // *** declare identifier? ***
     var owl_id = $(this).closest('.slider').prop('id'); // .attr('id'); // .prop('id');
     var owl_declare = $('#' + owl_id + ' .galleryowlmulti'); // owl_id.find('.galleryowlmulti'); // $('#' + owl_id + ' .galleryowlmulti'),
     var owl_instance = $('#' + owl_id + ' .owlcarousel'); // $(".owlcarousel", this) // owl_id.find('.owlcarousel'); // $('#' + owl_id + ' .owlcarousel');
    // pull variables from page
     var owl_owlthemes = owl_declare.data('owlthemes'),
     owl_owlitemshow = owl_declare.data('owlitemshow'),
     owl_owllazy = owl_declare.data('owllazy'),
     owl_owlmargin = owl_declare.data('owlmargin'),
     owl_owldots = owl_declare.data('owldots'),
     owl_owlautoplay = owl_declare.data('owlautoplay'),
     owl_owltimeout = owl_declare.data('owltimeout'),
     owl_slidebyf = owl_declare.data('owlslideby');

    // calc the items to show breaks
    var owl_owlitemshow75=Math.round(owl_owlitemshow*0.75), 
    owl_owlitemshow50=Math.round(owl_owlitemshow*0.5), 
    owl_owlitemshow25=Math.round(owl_owlitemshow*0.25);

    // calculate item count
    var item_count = parseInt(owl_instance.find('.item').length);
    var true_false = 0;
    if (item_count <=1) {true_false = false; owl_owldots = false;} else {true_false = true;}
    //
    // control nav visiblity thumbs shown vs thumbs allowed visible
    // see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33252395/3794783
    // owl_instance.on('initialized.owl.carousel resized.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    //    $(e.target).toggleClass('owl-nonav', e.item.count <= e.page.size);
    // }); 
    owl_instance.owlCarousel({
      themeClass: owl_owlthemes,
      autoplay: owl_owlautoplay,
      autoplayTimeout: owl_owltimeout,
      items: owl_owlitemshow,
      margin: owl_owlmargin,
      responsive:{
            0:{items:1,nav:true},
            389:{items:owl_owlitemshow25},
            605:{items:owl_owlitemshow50},
            1023:{items:owl_owlitemshow75},
            1289:{items:owl_owlitemshow}
       },
      loop: true_false, 
      nav: true_false,
      slideBy: owl_slidebyf,
      lazyLoad: owl_owllazy, // IMG markup (lazyOwl = V1 / owl-lazy = v2 ): class="owl-lazy" and data-src="url_to_img" src="" or/and data-src-retina="url_to_highres_img"
      dots: owl_owldots,
      //
      // backport the classes to older used ones
      navContainerClass: 'owl-buttons',
      dotsClass: 'owl-pagination',
      dotClass: 'owl-page',
      autoplayHoverPause:true, //false
      onInitialized: function() {
        if(owl_slidebyf == 'page'){
            owl_instance.owlCarousel({slideBy:page})
         }
      }     
    });

  });
});
```

Fiddle example:

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigegodesign/s0c7d0te/)

**UPDATE:**

I got some way along with getting mutliple instances on page to fire and work (-ish as lazyload isnt happy) ..

In the fiddle, remove or comment out the following:

```
responsive:{
    0:{items:1,nav:true},
    389:{items:owl_owlitemshow25},
    605:{items:owl_owlitemshow50},
    1023:{items:owl_owlitemshow75},
    1289:{items:owl_owlitemshow}
},
```

Ooops ... and this also needs commenting out or removing THEN it works? WTH?!

```
onInitialized: function() {
 if(owl_slidebyf == 'page'){
   owl_instance.owlCarousel({slideBy:page})
 }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Removing the "nav:true" in responsive seemed to fix .... seems to be the culprit for others reading ... if removed the original script code *should* work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some arrows (div, span, whatever) near the each carousel and assign to them class *.carousel-arrow-left* and *.carousel-arrow-right*. Next add this javascript to your js file.

**The Javascript**

```
// carousel arrows
$('.carousel-arrow-left').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".carousel-product-list").trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
$('.carousel-arrow-right').click(function(){
    $(this).prev(".carousel-product-list").trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

Let's say every carousel is called *.carousel-product-list*. Now every right arrow on your page after click finds next class which name is .carousel-product-list and do a command next.owl.carousel, which means the carousel go forward by a one item.

Comment: I'm so sorry Martin, and thanks for the reply .. i wasn't clear .. my problem is in trying to use one single block of javascript control code to manage multiple instances of the Owl slider in one page with each having its own distinct settings, such as how many items to show etc ... i just can't get the above to loop through each owl slider instance and activate .. the first slider instance in the page activates and works, but the rest do not and just show the raw slider html code. I hope i am making better sense. I amended the title of the question to hopefully better clarify.

Comment: added an fiddle for clarity.